# Sequelize (?): Save method stored in variable throws error when called: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNewRecord' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to store Sequelizes `instance.save` method in a variable to be called later. When I call it from that variable it throws error Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNewRecord' of undefined.

Save is performed on an associated object in array loaded thorough eager loading. If I call directly the code I'm trying to store, it works. It fails just when stored.

My code:

```
models.Person.hasMany(models.TaskExecutor, { foreignKey: 'personID' });
models.TaskExecutor.belongsTo(models.Person, { foreignKey: 'personID' });

const options = {
    include: [
        {
            model: models.TaskExecutor,
            where: { ... }
        }
    ]
};

let handler;

models.Person.findOne(options)
    .then(person => {
        handler = person.task_executors[0].save;
        handler().then(...); // THIS THROWS ERROR

        // HOWEVER
        person.task_executors[0].save().then(...); // WORKS JUST FINE
    })
```

Any idea what might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to bind the `this` keyword variable when creating the handler because the **save** method is a class method. You can do it like this:

```
const handler = person.task_executors[0].save.bind(person.task_executors[0]);
handler.then() ....
```

You can read more about `this` here https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thank you for making me check this. For some reason I thought it was not this reason. I'm still not accustomed to the 'this' binding issues.